# No such file or directory after running Strace in apache server

Tags: php, apache, joomla3.0

I am using Joomla 3.2 for my website, While running strace in Apache serve like below,

```
strace php index.php 2>&1 | grep 'write\|access'
```

I am getting below list of details (few of them)

```
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/share/dracut/modules.d/01fips", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/terminfo/x/xterm", R_OK)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/httpdocs/defines.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/httpdocs/installation/index.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/httpdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/httpdocs/libraries/cms/observer/mapper.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/httpdocs/libraries/cms/application/web.php", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

It displaying No such file or directory. But the website running smoothly. My client dont want to list these kind of details. Can anyone please take a look on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla has an web interface for installation, located in `"${pwd}/installation/index.php"`. The first thing Joomla does while bootstrapping is to check for the existence of that file, and running the installation if it does exist. Once installation is complete, the file is removed, but the check to see if Joomla needs to install is still there. So;

```
<?php
if (file_exists('installation/index.php')) {
   include 'installation/index.php';
   exit;
}
// rest of program.
```

This will show access in `strace`, because Joomla is trying to access an non existing file. It is a valid way of checking however.

The same probably goes for the rest of the files in your list. You can't do anything about it short of removing those checks, and truth be told: if your customer is concerned about strace output, they should at least know what matters, and what doesn't ;)

Comment: We have removed the installation folder at the time of installation of Joomla. Can you please tell me how can we remove these checks

Comment: @DelphinSam Like I said: it's not worth the trouble, if all you want to do is make sure that it doesn't show up in a debugging program such as `strace`. `strace` isn't a program for determining performance, it's for debugging issues. This isn't an issue.